# How do i print a pattern like this

Tags: python, for-loop

There is a question.
How do i print a pattern like this

```
stackoverflow
stackoverflo
 tackoverflo
 tackoverfl
  ackoverfl
  ackoverf
   ckoverf
   ckover
    kover
    kove
     ove
     ov
      v
```

I have tried to use for loops but failed...

```
str = "stackoverflow"
k = len(str)
print(str)
print(str[:(k-1)])
```

And I don't know how to use for loops to finish it
Are there any ways without using for loops to address this problem?
Thanks...

Comment: Why are you avoiding using for-loops? Using a for or while loop seems to be a natural way to do this. Yes, there might be ways to do this without doing a loop, but those ways may leave you more confused.

Comment: Then you will have to use a while loop

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is

```
s = "stackoverflow"
toggle = True # If true, remove first char. Else, cut last char.
left = 0 # number of spaces to prepend
right = 0 # number of spaces to append

while s: # while s is not empty
    print(' '*left + s + ' '*right)
    if toggle:
        s = s[1:] # remove first char
        left += 1
    else:
        s = s[:-1] # remove last char
        right += 1
    toggle = not toggle
```

which gives output

```
stackoverflow
 tackoverflow
 tackoverflo 
  ackoverflo 
  ackoverfl  
   ckoverfl  
   ckoverf   
    koverf   
    kover    
     over    
     ove     
      ve     
      v
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a `for` loop.  They're pretty easy to use once you get used to them.  Here's a solution that uses a `for` loop:

```
def show(s):
    n = len(s)
    for i in range(n):
        n1 = i // 2
        n2 = i - n1
        print(" " * n1 + s[n1:n-n2])

s = "stackoverflow"
show(s)
```

The output is:

```
stackoverflow
stackoverflo
 tackoverflo
 tackoverfl
  ackoverfl
  ackoverf
   ckoverf
   ckover
    kover
    kove
     ove
     ov
      v
```

If you really don't want to use a `for` loop, you can replace it with a `while` loop as follows:

```
i = 0
while i < n:
    ...
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of two index `l` and `r` that represent the slice of string to print. Then shorten that slice on each iteration.

```
s = 'stackoverflow'

l, r = 0, len(s)      # range of string to print
remove_left = True    # which side of the string to remove
space = 0             # how much space to print to the left

while l < r:
    print('%s%s' % (' ' * int(space/2), s[l:r]))

    if remove_left:
        r-= 1
    else:
        l+= 1

    remove_left = not remove_left
    space += 1
```

Output:

```
stackoverflow
stackoverflo
 tackoverflo
 tackoverfl
  ackoverfl
  ackoverf
   ckoverf
   ckover
    kover
    kove
     ove
     ov
      v
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use 'some_string'.rjust(width, ' ') where width is an integer value and the second parameter is a string in my example used a blank space. Also you can use 'some_string'.ljust(width, ' '). For more information you should check this site https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/rjust

for example:

```
def word_reduce(word):
   n = word.__len__()
   for i in range(n):
       left = i // 2 
       right = i - left
       result = word[left:n-right]
       print((' ').rjust(left + 1) + result)

s = 'stackoverflow'
word_reduce(s)
```

Comment: Write up some code as to what you this can be the answer rather than point to a reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of recursion

```
def stackoverflow(pattern,alternate=0):
    if len(pattern) == 1:
        #base condition for recursion
        return 
    elif alternate == 0:
        #first time execution
        print(pattern)
        alternate = alternate + 1
        stackoverflow(pattern, alternate)
    elif alternate % 2 != 0:
        # truncate from right side
        pattern = pattern[:-1]
        print(pattern)
        alternate = alternate + 1
        stackoverflow(pattern, alternate)
    else:
        #truncate from left side
        pattern = pattern[1:]
        print(pattern)
        alternate = alternate + 1
        stackoverflow(pattern,alternate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with only one counter

```
string = "stackoverflow"
loop=0
while string.replace(' ','')!='':
   print(' '*(loop//2)+string+' '*(loop//2))
   if loop%2==0:
       string=string[:-1]
   else:
       string=string[1:]
   loop=loop+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just simple slice operator :

```
a='stackoverflow'
print(a)

    #printing first whole string
    for i in range(len(a)):
        #loop range of the string

        if i%2==0:
            #here the logic see the problem you will find a pattern that it removing
            #last character when loop number is even and update the string with current
            #sliced string
            #print(i)
            # if you want use this print for understanding track of slicing
            print('{:^12s}'.format(a[:-1]))

            #Removing last character if loop index is even
            a=a[:-1]
            #update the string with current sliced string
        else:
            #print(i)
            #use this print for tracking of sliced string
            print('{:^14s}'.format(a[1:]))
            #remove first character if loop index is not even or loop index is odd.

            a=a[1:]
            #update the current string with sliced string
```

output:

```
stackoverflow
stackoverflo
 tackoverflo  
 tackoverfl 
  ackoverfl   
  ackoverf  
   ckoverf    
   ckover   
    kover     
    kove    
     ove      
     ov     
      v
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP stated that no loops. Does hardcoding count as valid answer?

```
print(“stackoverflow”)
print(“stackoverflo”)
print(“ tackoverflo”)
print(“ tackoverfl”)
print(“  ackoverfl”)
print(“  ackoverf”)
print(“   ckoverf”)
print(“   ckover”)
print(“    kover)
print(“    kove”)
print(“     ove”)
print(“     ov”)
print(“      v”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with **recursive function** `printline()`. **For loop** not needed.

```
# Recursive function
def printline(string, cutleft, padindex):
    # Print out the required line
    print(string.rjust(padindex+len(string)))

    # Last character to print out
    if len(string) == 1:
        return

    # Deciding to trim the left or right part of the string
    if cutleft:
        printline(string[1:], 0, padindex + 1)
    else:
        printline(string[:-1], 1, padindex)

# Calling the recursive function with initial value
printline('stackoverflow', 0, 0)
```

This is the output.

```
stackoverflow
stackoverflo
 tackoverflo
 tackoverfl
  ackoverfl
  ackoverf
   ckoverf
   ckover
    kover
    kove
     ove
     ov
      v
```